# How to keep a MS Word installation working after exchanging HDD without license key at hand?

Tags: ms-office, upgrade, license, hdd

I changed the HDD of a Macbook with OS X Yosemite by taking the HDD out of the computer and making a byte-by-byte copy with `dd` on Linux. Now MS Word refuses to start saying the copy isn't licensed. It seems to calculate a checksum over the license key and hardware serial numbers and fail due to the change of the HDD.

I have both HDDs at hand and could restore the old installation by putting in the old HDD. How can I prepare MS Word (license) to survive the HDD change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recover my MS Office 2011 product key?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62947/how-can-i-recover-my-ms-office-2011-product-key)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy

/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist

from the old machine to the new one.  Make sure you put it into the exact same location.

Comment: That doesn't work - how could it the old and the new drive have been copied byte-by-byte, moving files can't change anything.